# How to not add caret ^ sign to package installed with yarn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I saw a solution for npm to change version prefix https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-prefix. What's the solution for [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) to not add caret?

I'd like to configure it not globally, but only for current project, if possible.

So, when I run something like `yarn add --dev webpack`, it saves its version as `"webpack": "3.6.0"`, not `"webpack": "^3.6.0"`.

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add#toc-yarn-add-exact-e ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do

```
$ yarn config set save-prefix false
```

or

```
$ echo save-prefix false >> .yarnrc
```

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/config/

---

### Edit

setting the value to `false` will install packages like this `"some-package": "false3.0.4"`, which can be a bit misleading. If you **don't** want a prefix at all then set it to an empty string via `yarn config set save-prefix ""`

Comment: Just what's needed, but I had to put `save-prefix ""` into `.yarnrc`. When there was `false`, it just added as a string prefix `"false"`.

Comment: Don't know why this is the chosen answer, maybe on old yarn version this worked correct but for yarn 1.9,2 it is lik @SergeiBasharov said, don't use `false`, put empty string instead.

Comment: `yarn config set save-prefix false` worked fine with yarn version 1.15.2. I did not have to set it to an empty string as @SergeiBasharov mentioned.

Comment: @Antony I tried the way you suggested and it adds it as a string:
   `"@types/koa": "false2.0.48",
    "koa": "false2.7.0"`

Comment: @SergeiBasharov nope, this is not how it behaves in my Ubuntu 18.04. Are you using yarn `1.15.2`?

Comment: @Antony exactly, mine is 1.15.2 and I am on MacOS

Comment: That is strange. After running `yarn config set save-prefix false`, my ~/.yarnrc has the line `save-prefix false`, and it works perfectly. It does not add "false" prefix to the package versions.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone looking for a `Yarn 2` solution, add `.yarnrc.yml` with the following content:

```yaml
defaultSemverRangePrefix: ""
```

Reference: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc

Answer (score 3):

As it is not mentioned in @Noel's answer, you can run this if you don't want to do `yarn config ...` and don't want to have `false` prefix:

```
echo save-prefix \"\" >> .yarnrc
```

It puts the following in `.yarnrc`:

`save-prefix ""`

which installs packages for the current project without any prefix.

*Note:* `""` means empty string, i.e. put nothing as a prefix.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the correct answer is to use https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/#toc-yarn-add-exact-e

Example:

```sh
yarn add @soldeplata/popper-vue -E
```

or

```sh
yarn add @soldeplata/popper-vue --exact
```

Comment: Definitely the least hacky way to do it in my opinion